# Spring Data JPA - @Query with null values based on user input

Tags: spring, jpa

The user has a form:

- checkbox with fields **status** and **priority**
- submit btn

**Objective**: Query DB based on these values.
If one of them is null or false, the criteria should be ignored.
Ex: **status** is checked and **priority** is not, I want to query only based on status.

The code below will never execute with one of them being false. I also read about [Query by Example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example) but could not find a solution.
Null values can indeed be ignored, but need to be previously defined.

I thought about replacing null with something similar to *.
Ex: WHERE c.status = *. It didn't work.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tickets c WHERE c.status = :status AND c.priority= :priority",
    nativeQuery = true)
    List<Ticket> findByFilter(@Param("status") String status,
                              @Param("priority") String priority);
```

Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: You should use a Specificication to create a dynamic query instead

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Simon for pointing me in the right direction.

This was the web page that helped me:
https://dimitr.im/writing-dynamic-queries-with-spring-data-jpa

My situation:

Created a specification class:

```
public final class DbFilterSpecification {
  public static Specification<Ticket> statusContains(String expression) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> builder.like(root.get("status"), contains(expression));
  }

  public static Specification<Ticket> priorityContains(String expression) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> builder.like(root.get("priority"), contains(expression));
  }

  private static String contains(String expression) {
    return MessageFormat.format("%{0}%", expression);
  }
}
```

Created a method inside the service layer:

```
public List<Ticket> findAllWithSpecification(String status, String priority) {
  Specification<Ticket> specification = Specification
    .where(status == null ? null : DbFilterSpecification.statusContains(status))
    .and(priority == null ? null : DbFilterSpecification.priorityContains(priority));
  return ticketRepository.findAll(specification);
}
```